# Could I say "this March" to mean the March which just passed?

Tags: word-usage

My question is if I could say "this March" to mean the March which just passed.

Comment: You can, but _this past March_ would be less ambiguous.

Comment: What @J.R.♦ said. Note that if you want to unambiguously reference the March which will arrive 12 months after the one which [just] passed, you can use *this **coming** March*. But the longer ago (or the further in the future) the referenced month falls, the more likely we'd be to just use the more common forms ***last / next** March*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. "This", "next", and "last" with a time period such as a day, week, month or year, are all potentially ambiguous. I think that "this" is more often used of the future than the past, but with a past-tense verb, it clearly means the most recent instance in the past (and avoids the possible ambiguity of "last March").

Comment: I don't *necessarily* disagree, but I'm not exactly convinced that "this" is more often used of the future than the past. *I've been really busy this past week,* for example, sounds perfectly natural to me. I think the main effect of using "this" is simply to emphasise "immediacy, relevance to time of utterance".

Comment: @FumbleFingers. You may be right. But "this past" is entirely different from "this", in that it has no ambiguity.

Comment: Indeed. But I'd also say that I *really* don't much like the idea of referring to *this past March* in, say, January. I think it's partly to do with potential confusion regarding ***this** year* and ***last** year*, but that's not the whole story. Per my comment to the question, if the month being referenced is significantly more than half a year away (in the past ***or***   the future), ***this*** seems increasingly "awkward". So I don't much like *this past March* in December either, even though it's still ***this** year*.